# What's the equivalent to Form::buttonClicked in SS4?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

In SilverStripe 3, if I want to find out what button was clicked on a form (after it was submitted), I would call:

```
$form->buttonClicked()->actionName();
```

`buttonClicked` appears to have been removed in SilverStripe 4, does anyone have any idea how you would do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I worked this out, you have to get it from the request handler now, something like:

```
$handler = $>form->getRequestHandler();
$action = $handler->buttonClicked();
```